# AngularJS - another injector issue

Tags: angularjs

what is wrong with this dependency injection? Every time I inject modalController into... well, anything... I get an injector error. Ive included the js file as a script reference, and Ive referenced my modal module. Here is the actual error:

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.13/$injector/unpr?p0=modalControllerProvider%20%3C-%20modalController

```
personnelModule.controller('PersonnelController', ['$scope', 'personnelFactory','modalController', function($scope, personnelFactory, modalController){
    personnelFactory.getPersonnel().then(function(personnel){
        $scope.personnel = personnel;
        $scope.events = {};
        $scope.events.addPerson = function() {
            $modal.open({
              templateUrl: '../SiteAssets/views/ModalTemplate.html',
              controller: modalController
            });
        };
    });
}]);

modalModule.controller('modalController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function($scope, $modalInstance){
      $scope.ok = function () {
        alert('ok clicked');
        $modalInstance.dismiss('canceled'); 
      };
      $scope.cancel = function () {
        alert('cancel clicked');
        $modalInstance.dismiss('canceled'); 
      };
}]);
```

Comment: Maybe you haven't injected `modalModule` as a dependency for `personnelModule`? When instantiating `personnelModule`, you would do `angular.module("personnelModule", ["modalModule"])`, in order to make `modalController` available (assuming you instantiated `modalModule` as `angular.module("modalModule", [])`).

Comment: my modules look like this: var modalModule = angular.module('modal', ['ui.bootstrap']); and var personnelModule = angular.module('personnel', ['skills', 'modal', 'ui.bootstrap']); Also, I can successfully inject factories in that module. This also doesn't work if I try to inject within the same module.

Comment: Looks like that should work fine! The only other thing I can think of is the order in which your js files are loaded. Perhaps you are initialising your `modalModule` before `personnelModule` so that it exists and doesn't throw an error when `personnelModule` is initialised, but maybe your `personnelController` is initialised before `modalController` has been declared? I'm only assuming this because th e fact that your modules are stored in variables hints that you might be scattering stuff from the same module across different files.

Comment: As a side note, if you only need to set the controller of the modal you can use `controller: 'modalController'`

Comment: im storing my modules in variables because im new to this and that's how it was taught on the google tutorial, but im actually keeping everything associated with the module in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try referencing the controller as a string. (in the $modal.open)

```
controller: 'modalController'
```

#### EDIT

You also need to inject the $modal service into the 'PersonnelController' and I believe injecting the 'modalController' is unnecessary.

```
personnelModule.controller('PersonnelController', ['$scope', 'personnelFactory', '$modal', function($scope, personnelFactory, $modal){
```

#### EDIT 2

Try [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tsllfkl3T4OMZo3orIKX?p=preview). The most notable changes I made were removing the

```
<div ng-controller="modalController"></div>
```

and

```
<button ... ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
```

Comment: nope... still doesn't work. I assume you mean in the $modal.open function... right? In fact, even if I remove controller: modalController from that function, I get the same error

Comment: Yeah you are right -- sorry about the ambiguity.  What exactly is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Well, removing the modalController injection certainly prevents that error, but my modal buttons which are controlled by that controller also don't work... the modal HTML is wrapped in a div with ng-controller="modalController" and my buttons are ng-click="ok" and ng-click="cancel"... I think that's right? So im not sure the modalController is actually getting called...

Comment: the error I get is: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.13/$injector/unpr?p0=modalControllerProvider%20%3C-%20modalController

Comment: Well you do not need to define the controller in the modal HTML so I would remove that (though I am not sure it is causing your problem).  Can you make a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: Never used plunker but I tried to mock this up, leaving out irrelevant code. I cant seem to get it running though... angular doesn't do its thing (probably user error): http://plnkr.co/edit/7aM0iBLl5MRWLEPhala8?p=preview

Comment: You got it - thanks! I don't really understand why you have to inject every dependency, but not inject this. I also don't understand why injecting it did not work, even if unnecessary. Ultimately, it works now, so ill just take this as an exception. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do not inject controllers into each other. I mean, why would you want to do that??